# GreenDAO does not persist data across application restart

Tags: android, greendao

I want to use GreenDAO for persistence, but I cannot get it to persist my data.

The data is saved and loaded correctly as long as the application is not restarted.

Once i swipe the app away and reopen it from scratch, GreenDAO does not see the previous data (both on the emulator and real device).

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
public class TestSingleEntity {
    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    Long id;

    int someNumber;

    public TestSingleEntity(int someNumber) {
        this.someNumber = someNumber;
    }

    @Generated(hash = 787203968)
    public TestSingleEntity(Long id, int someNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.someNumber = someNumber;
    }

    @Generated(hash = 1371368161)
    public TestSingleEntity() {
    }
// ... some more stuff
}
```

This is how I insert entities to database:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
TestSingleEntity singleEntity = new TestSingleEntity();
singleEntity.setSomeNumber(rnd.nextInt());

DaoSession session = ((MyApp)getApplication()).getDaoSession();
TestSingleEntityDao dao = session.getTestSingleEntityDao();
dao.insert(singleEntity);

Log.d("tgd", "Inserted an entity with id " + singleEntity.getId());
```

And this is how I read them:
    Query query = dao.queryBuilder().orderAsc(TestSingleEntityDao.Properties.SomeNumber).build();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

```
List<TestSingleEntity> result = query.list();
Log.d("size", result.size());
for (TestSingleEntity testSingleEntity : result) {
    Log.d("entity", testSingleEntity.toString());
}
```

As I have said, as long as I stay in the app (moving around in different activities is okay), everytime the `insert` is called, a new entity with a new ID is created. As soon as I relaunch the app, it goes back to square one.

The setup was taken directly from the [GitHub page](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/examples/DaoExample/src/main/java/org/greenrobot/greendao/example/App.java). What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: GreenDAO has gone through major changes since I last used it so this is purely based on reading their code on the github.

Apparently GreenDAO's poorly documented [DevOpenHelper](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/DaoGenerator/src-template/dao-master.ftl#L114) drops all tables on upgrade, so the real question is why is `onUpgrade` being called when clearly there hasn't been a change to the schema version. Try to look for the log line that mentions dropping the tables as described in the template for `DevOpenHelper`.

Regardless, using `OpenHelper` instead should fix the issue.